# Ubuntu works so slow no matter what I try

Tags: partitioning, lubuntu, performance, swap, cpu

So I have installed ubuntu 20LTS for a computer that was assigned to me but it is a painful to use it because it boots in 10 minutes. But that is not it, it is really slow, opening  a tab from firefox makes the system wait for 10 minutes and it sometimes won't even bother with opening it and just gives error. Even running simple commands from terminal is sometimes takes really long time.
Here are the list of stuff that I tried but result in fail

1- Increased the swap space.
I increased the swap space from 2 to 4 gb, which did not make any difference. Plus, I don't  think I have memory issues, the following is the result of

```
free -m
```

command

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           5934         564        4619          12         751        5119
Swap:          4095           0        4095
```

2- changed cpu to performence to ondemand
I thought it might be because ubuntu cpu's are in powersave mode but nothing changed when I changed cpu to performence.

3-  cpu usage
I don't think it is about cpu usage either, the result of the top command:

```
top - 08:33:11 up 36 min,  1 user,  load average: 3,76, 3,68, 4,11
Tasks: 230 total,   1 running, 228 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
%Cpu(s):  1,1 us,  0,7 sy,  0,0 ni, 46,5 id, 51,7 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,1 si,  0,0 st
MiB Mem :   5934,6 total,   3368,5 free,   1209,8 used,   1356,3 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   4096,0 total,   4096,0 free,      0,0 used.   4451,7 avail Mem
```

4- Disabled animation from gnome-tweak tools,
Nothing changed

5- Installed lubuntu for greater performence
Nothing changed

I am out of options now, you might think my pc specs are trash but I am running dualboot win10 on it ant it is working perfectly.

Comment: ubuntu cpu's are in powersave mode An OS does not have CPU hardware does. You have not said what the hardware is or if it even meets the needs of Ubuntu 20.4 LTS (the actual version number*

Comment: hi, sorry I forgot to include system specs, Processor: AMD Ryzen 3 2200G with Radeon Vega Graphics, 3500 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 4 Logical Processor(s)                   Installed Physical Memory (RAM) 8.00 GB                                                                       
and 500 gb of space, so I believe that should be enough for ubuntu.                                  Furthermore, as I mentioned cpus are not in powersave mode, I changed them to performence mode

Comment: Do you have Ubuntu installed to an external hard drive or something?

Comment: Not really. I have two different memories in PC and partitioned one of them to ubuntu

Comment: I would start by looking at your logs. Everything you need should be in `/var/log`. The first step isn't fixing, it is figuring out what needs fixed. This may sound obvious, but it should be at the front of your mind. Otherwise, you'll waste time spinning your wheels. There are a few programs that come with Ubuntu that show you the combined output from multiple sources logs in a readable way, and let you filter, so that you have fine-grained control over which messages are displayed.

Comment: My favorite tool for this is `journalctl`. Just reading the output of `man journalctl` carefully will make the process of tracking down the issue much easier. If you want to know more about the process, I am willing to post a descriptive answer on the topic as it pertains to your situation, but you need to let me know that it is what you are looking for.

Comment: I will really appreciate if you post a descriptive answer, I really would like to know what is happenning to system. Currently working on something else, but I will be back to ubuntu in a couple of hours, so I can post the results.

Comment: Your load average is pretty high. Clearly the machine is busy doing *something* while you’re asking it to do more. If it’s always like this, from boot to shutdown, then there may be an IO scheduling issue 

Comment: hi, I couldn't see anything aout cpu usage, here is the result of ps aux

Comment: the result of ps aux shows no process that consumes more than 1 percent of cpu. On the other hand i used                                     'iostat -d 30 /dev/sda' and it showed me  some stuff

Comment: 'Device             tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_dscd/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn   ' 'kB_dscd'
sda               4,59       127,63        44,53         0,00    1026643     358177          0                                                            


Device             tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_dscd/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn    kB_dscd                                                                                               
sda               0,13         0,00         0,93         0,00          0         28          0 '